# Is there any effect on code performance after fixing PMD "CollapsibleIfStatements" violations?

Tags: java, optimization, pmd

Is there any effect on code after fixing PMD "CollapsibleIfStatements" violations?
From code effect I mean to ask if the code becomes more optimized? Or only readability? If it is optimized than in what sense?

That did not solve my problem. I am asking about is there any optimization to code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CollapsibleIfStatements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411107/collapsibleifstatements)

Comment: That did not solve my problem. I am asking about is there any optimization to code?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in performance. Thanks to short-circuiting the following code produces the same bytecode:

```java
class CollapsibleIfStatements {

    void collapsedIfStatements(boolean first, boolean second, boolean third) {
        if (first && second && third) {   
        }
    }

    void nestedIfStatements(boolean first, boolean second, boolean third) {
        if (first) {
            if (second) {
                if (third) {       
                }       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This rule is about avoiding nesting to improve readability and reduce the need for multiple closing braces at the end:

```java
                } 
            }       
        }
    }
}
```